# print_r($_REQUEST) not showing all datas after showing few datas

Tags: php

`print_r($_REQUEST)` is not showing all the datas after redirecting from a page  from which form  is being submitted. In the redirected page it is showing some datas but not all.In the localhost all the requested datas are showing fine,but in the server the problem is occurring.
I have created a `php.ini` & put `max_execution_time = 160; post_max_size = 250M;` into the file & uploaded it in the server. But still couldn't get any solution.

Here is code. Actually some page are included after checking condition and then the form is being submitted after filling fields.

```
include("configuration.php");
if(isset($_REQUEST["save_update"]) && $_REQUEST["save_update"]!="")
{
   include("quotation_save.php");
   header("location:http://mpsinfoservices.com/projects/topline/quotation.php?enquiry_id=".$_REQUEST["enquiry_id"]."&displaying_id=".$_REQUEST["displaying_id"]);
}
$enqid = $_REQUEST["enquiry_id"];
$displaying_id = $_REQUEST["displaying_id"];
$len_of_disp = strlen($displaying_id);
/*if(preg_match('/E/',$displaying_id))
{
  echo substr($displaying_id,0,6);
  echo "<br/>".substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)));
  if(preg_match('/F/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
  $ch_from_find_str = 'F';
  $find_str = substr($displaying_id,0,7);
  $ch_from_find_str = substr($find_str,6,1);

}
if(preg_match('/PKG/',$displaying_id))
{
  $find_str = substr($displaying_id,0,9);
  echo $find_str;
}
*/
$sql_enquiry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `enquiry_master` WHERE `id`='".$enqid."' AND `displaying_id`='".$displaying_id."'");
$row_enquiry = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_enquiry);
$sql_client_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client_info` WHERE `client_id`='".$row_enquiry['customer_id']."'");
$row_client_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_client_info);
?>
<link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/function.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
  .client_name
  {
    border:none;
  }
  .client_name_mouseover
  {
    border:1px solid #000;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
    <div id="page-container">
        <?php
            include("includes/left_menu.php");
        ?>
        <div id="page_content" style="float:left;">
            <div style="margin-top:25px;">
            <div style="padding-top:10px;">
                <div style="color:#000;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;">Client Details</div>
                <div>Name:- <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" class="client_name" value="<?php echo $row_client_info["client_firstname"].$row_client_info["client_middlename"].$row_client_info["client_lastname"];?>" readonly="readonly"/></div>
                <div>Email:- <?php echo $row_client_info["client_email_id"]; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
            <?php
              $sql_quotation_insert_status = mysql_query("SELECT `status` FROM `quotation_insert_status` WHERE `enquiry_id`='".$enqid."'");
              if( mysql_num_rows($sql_quotation_insert_status)>0)
              {
              $res_quotation_insert_status = "insert";
              }
              else
              {

                $res_quotation_insert_status = "";
              }

            ?>
            <form name="quotation" class="quotationfrm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="quotation.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="displaying_id" value="<?php echo $displaying_id; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="enquiry_id" value="<?php echo $enqid; ?>"/>

            <input type="hidden" name="save_update" <?php if($res_quotation_insert_status=="insert"){?>value="update" <?php } if($res_quotation_insert_status==""){?> value="save_quotation" <?php } ?>/>
            <?php
             if(preg_match('/E/',$displaying_id))
            {
              if(preg_match('/F/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/flight_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/T/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/train_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/H/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/hotel_quotation2.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/CC/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/carrental_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/I/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/insurance_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/V/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/visa_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/CR/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,6)))))
              {
                include("quotation/cruise_quotation.php");
              }
            }
            if(preg_match('/PKG/',$displaying_id))
            {
               if(preg_match('/H/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/hotel_quotation2.php");
              }
              include("quotation/package_quotation.php");

              if(preg_match('/F/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/flight_quotation.php");
              }
               if(preg_match('/V/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/visa_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/T/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/train_quotation.php");
              }

              if(preg_match('/CC/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/carrental_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/I/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/insurance_quotation.php");
              }
              if(preg_match('/CR/',substr($displaying_id,strlen(substr($displaying_id,0,7)))))
              {
                include("quotation/cruise_quotation.php");
              }


            }
            ?>

            <input type="button" class="save_quotation" <?php if($res_quotation_insert_status=="insert"){?> value="Update" <?php } if($res_quotation_insert_status==""){ ?> value="Save The Quotation" <?php } ?> style="margin-top:20px;" <?php if($res_quotation_insert_status=="insert"){ ?> name="save" <?php } if($res_quotation_insert_status==""){ ?> name="update" <?php } ?>/>
            <?php if($res_quotation_insert_status=="insert"){?>
              <input type="button" class="sendQuotation" value="Send Quotation"/>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            </form>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  $(function(){
    var no=0;

      $("form").each(function(){
        no++;
      });
      var suc = 0;

      $("#client_name").live("mouseover",function(){
          $(this).removeClass("client_name");
          $(this).addClass("client_name_mouseover");
      });
       $("#client_name").live("mouseout",function(){
          $(this).removeClass("client_name_mouseover");
          $(this).addClass("client_name");
      });
      $(".mail_to_client").live("click",function(){
            $.post("flight_quotation_mail.php?enquiry_id=<?php echo $enqid; ?>",$(".flight_quotation_frm").serialize(),function(data){
                if(data=="success")
                {
                  suc++;
                }
                if(no==suc)
                {
                  $.post("mail_to_client.php?enquiry_id=<?php echo $enqid; ?>");
                }
            });
            $.post("train_quotation_mail.php?enquiry_id=<?php echo $enqid; ?>",$(".train_quotation_frm").serialize(),function(data){
                if(data=="success")
                {
                  suc++;

                }
                if(no==suc)
                {
                  $.post("mail_to_client.php?enquiry_id=<?php echo $enqid; ?>");

                }
            });
            /*$.post("hotel_quotation_mail.php?enquiry_id=<?php echo $enqid; ?>",$(".hotel_quotation_frm").serialize(),function(data){
                if(data=="success")
                {
                  suc++;

                }
                if(no==suc)
                {
                  $.post("mail_to_client.php?enquiry_id=<?php echo $enqid; ?>");

                }
            });*/
        });
        $(".save_quotation").live("click",function(){
            $(".quotationfrm").submit();
        });

         $(".sendQuotation").live("click",function(){
         for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances)
        CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
                       var formData = $(".quotationfrm").serialize();

                               $.post("quotation_pdf.php",function(){
                                       window.open("quotation_pdf.php?"+formData);
                               });
  });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you submit the form to one place, then redirect to another? REQUEST vars are not retained across further requests than the submission.

Comment: can post the data variables you're submitting and also what exist and missing in the $_REQUEST please?

Comment: Check your form fields name, it should be unique for each field.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases due to html elements in the data it will render only few, try checking View Source of that page.

Answer (score 0):

The content and order of `$_REQUEST` is affected by `variables_order` directive in `php.ini` (see [Description of core php.ini directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order))

So, it is possible, that on your production environment value of `variables-order` directive differs from that in your development environment (localhost).

For example, set `variables_order = "GPCS"` in order to have G-`$_GET`, P-`$_POST`, C-`$_COOKIE`, S-`$_SERVER` arrays and all values from that arrays in `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I have set variables_order = "GPCS" in my php.ini but still having the same problem.